# How to inject parameters into return function with custom hook react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, partial-application

Usually when we use `<input />` field in html, we get a callback function such as `<input onChange = {(event) => console.log(event.target.value)}` How is this `event` argument passed back to us?

I am trying to do something similar, where I use a custom hook that, when called, does some other logic, and then can return back callback functions and inject arguments into them. For example:

```
const hello = useHello({
    arg1 : 'person name',
    onSuccess : (response) => {
         // I can now use the response
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hook you just create a `response` however you need to, and then pass it to the `onSuccess` function that was passed in.

For example:

```
function useHello({
  arg1,
  onSuccess
}: {
  arg1: string,
  onSuccess: (response: Response) => void
}) {
  fetch(`/?${arg1}`).then((res) => {
    onSuccess(res)
  })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwBJoDbbgCgG8BYAKEUQEMAnAcwEYAaMihAZRAgjRRTIF8AXIhLkqdesJRRqMMLWZj2nbr2H5qPAA4J0wgErbdaAJSIAvAD5EANzgwAJgLOiKwNFAgALfAAMA9AD8ACSENAz8viYAdFBeaGD4GjxmViIsFIjKXDwoySgmGfyFpPxkZKiYOHhEGRTh9IjCAORaaNQoCIhglAC2aM2KmVlgHDm8TYj5OmDoqdauw8P+-ogAkogQlEhgcADuyOiIcWiImigz6HWIZaUmANxAA)